# Background Color in Yahoo Mail not displayed - shown as white

Tags: css, email, yahoo

In Yahoo mail, HTML of nested table does not show selected BG Colour, instead it seems to reset and display white.

```
<table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="369">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#203c02">
<td bgcolor="#203c02" style="background-color:#203c02;" height="400">
<p style="font-family: Arial; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 10px;"><strong>Hi $$first_name$$.</strong></p>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the html you think is in the email or the actual html copied from the email source?

Comment: Hi, its the actual HTML source before sent as an email

Comment: Then you should see the source from within the email, yahoo may change it or filter out certain parts.

Comment: I'm using Litmus to test and believe that Yahoo do filter out and display different bg colours within their own client. thanks for your comment.